# " 404 Not Found [IP: ] " when try to install any ros kinetic package

Tags: ubuntu, ros, apt

I was trying to install the rtabmap_ros package in the ROS kinetic. But I have got the `"404 not found [IP:]" error`. So I tried to install any other ROS packages and I found that I can't install any ROS package and get the same error. Also when I run `apt-get update` actually the ROS repositories do not update.

I usually use a VPN, so I tried it with the VPN off, but it did not solve it. Also, running below command from ROS kinetic installation guide but it also did not work for me.

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654`

In `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` file I have two files for ROS. `"ros-latest.list"` and `"ros.latest.list.save"`. These files contain same context as below:

`deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main`

`deb-src http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main`

I searched through my "source.list" file to find anything about ROS but there was nothing relevant to ROS in there.

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Not enough details. 1) Please show the exact command you run ( e.g. apt-get install ... ) 2) Please show your apt repositories configuration. ( something that usually in /etc/apt/ directory )

Comment: i use "sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rtabmap-ros".

Comment: i actually dont know how to give you configuration of repository

Comment: is it in a specific file?

Comment: i edited my question. i hope that contain enough data. but if not please let me know to add further information. thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Error:**

```
Err: http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu eoan Release
404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
```

**It works for me:**

Step 1: switch to the corresponding PPA directory:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

Step 2: in the directory run ls, you can see the corresponding *.list, in my case webupd8team-ubuntu-java-eoan.list, delete the .list file (for safety, don't delete, just add a suffix .bak backup)
The command is as follows:

```
sudo mv webupd8team-ubuntu-java-eoan.list webupd8team-ubuntu-java-eoan.list.bak
```

You can list again, for see details.

Step 3: Check whether the problem is solved

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Original Source: https://www.cnblogs.com/wenzheshen/p/6599636.html

Answer (score 1):

This is actually for changing the key of the ROS repositories. You must delete the old key and add the new key.

`old key : 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116`

`new key : C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654`

So for solving this run the below commands:

`sudo apt-key del 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116`

`sudo -E apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654`

`sudo apt clean && sudo apt update`

This actually worked for me.